# Can we use BrowserRouter Switch and Route from react-router-dom in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I am new to React Native. as in react we can use following routes

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
const App = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
      <Layout>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
        </Switch>
      </Layout>
    </Router>
  </Provider>
  );
```

Can we use these(BrowserRouter,Route,Switch and provider) in React Native?

if Yes then please explain how its possible otherwise please explain any alternatives of these.

Answer (score 1):

react-router-dom is not working in react native you have to use [react navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/) in react native for navigation

there are different options available in react-navigation for routing such as NavigationContainer,stack,createDrawerNavigator,tab etc.

Comment: And what about provider? Is it can be used in React native?

Comment: provider and context apis are working same as react

Answer (score 0):

Instead of react-router-dom, you can use react-router-native in your react-native app. I think it is much easier for you if you are new in react-native to pick it up with things that you know!